# AngularJS service with Java (REST)?

Tags: java, javascript, rest, angularjs

I generated a simple java REST service with netbeans and it is working and now I need to make a AngularJS controller and service to get some data (nothing special).
I never used angularjs before and I probably made a mistake in the `service.js` because nothing is displaying in my `index.html`.

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);

angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])
.factory('myService',['$resource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('http://localhost:8080/IntelWebPlayer/webresources/ch.eiafr.iwp.backend.viewtimestamp', {}, {
    query: {method: 'GET'}
    })
  }])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','myService', function ($scope,myService) {
var b = myService.query();
alert(b);
$scope.timestamp = myService;
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        {{ timestamp }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me or redirect me to a good tutorial ?
The only thing I found was : http://draptik.github.io/blog/2013/07/13/angularjs-example-using-a-java-restful-web-service/

Comment: Can you show the index.html page as well?

Comment: kindly check browser console and let me know what error you r getting?

Answer (score 0):

You might try this [AngularJS Step-by-Step: Services](http://blog.pluralsight.com/angularjs-step-by-step-services) or [Spring's consuming RESTful w/AngularJS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/). Most of these appear to be written with AngularJS 1.0 in mind, so some differences in 1.2 may come into play.

Comment: Try to have the key points of the websites in your answer, incase the `URL` changes